# How to solve the error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

I have code where I should check complicated condition several times. F.E: `(a && b) || c`, etc. I tried to add variable with my condition like `const hasSomething = (a && b) || c`, and I faced with issue with TS which I can't solve.

Example Works:

```
function add(a?: number, b?: number): number {

    if (a && b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
function add(a?: number, b?: number): number {
    const hasNumbers = a && b;

    if (hasNumbers) {
        return a + b;
               ^   ^
               TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is is any workaround to fix it without non-null assertion `!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to fix :D. Just update the version of TypeScript to 4.4:

```js
function add(a?: number, b?: number): number {
    const hasNumbers = a && b;
    if (hasNumbers) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBTIPwC5FggC2ARgKYBOANIiXgceRQJT6GmWIDeAsAFCJBiCAgDOURAAtkogHKNKoxAF4UiAGTraAbn5DEMYIgzS5CiqObc9%20oRTJQQFJMkQBqHTcEBfL4nuOzogADLp83kA)

Answer (score 1):

the && (and) operator with number doesn't work as expected:

if you use it like this:

```js
const foo = 3 && 4
```

you can see that the `typeof foo` is `"number"`.

In fact the && operators returns:

- the last number if the result will be true, example: `5 && 4` is `true` so it will return `4`
- the falsy value is there is one: example `0 && 4` has `0` as false value and will return `0`, same with `undefined && 4` this will return `undefined`

TypeScript versions lower than `4.4.0` will not truly understand which will be the real result due to the fact that it could be `undefined` AFAIK.

that said is also a bad practice using `number && number` when at least one of the two values can be `0` due to the fact that `0` is a falsy value and in your function any sum with 0 in it will result in a `0` response according to the `a && b` check.

I suggest you to just make the function parameters mandatory in order to avoid the error and avoid the `hasNumbers` check:

```js
function add(a: number, b: number): number {

    return a + b
}
```